# Horizontal list item width when text is wrapped

Tags: html, css

I have a horizontal menu: https://jsfiddle.net/4dzrto3v/2/

What I want to achive is to reduce item width, when text i wrapped. If you look at second element, there is a space on right that I want to reduce to minimum.

```css
#nav {
  width: 100%;
  height: 4em; 
  background: #F0C000;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

#nav li {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  font-size: 1em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  height: 4em;
  padding-right: 1em;
  max-width: 8em;
  border-right: 1px solid #fff
}

#nav a:link, #nav a:active, #nav a:visited , #nav a:hover { 
  color: #444; 
  text-decoration: none;
}

#nav li:hover {
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<ul id="nav">
  <li>First</li>
  <li>Second element</li>
  <li>Third element</li>
  <li>Fourth element with long text</li>
  <li>Fifth</li>
</ul>
```

If I remove `max-width` property, then there isn't word break and text is single line.

Here is an illustration of the menu I want (notice second element width).

[image]

Comment: Delete max-width or change its property

Comment: you possibly *can't* do that unless you opt for something like `word-break: break-all` or `text-align: justify`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using float property on the *li* element, you can try with flex :

```
#nav{
    width: 100%;
    height: 4em;    
    background: #F0C000;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    display:flex;
}

#nav li{
    position: relative;
    font-size: 1em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    height: 4em;
    padding-right: 1em;
    border-right: 1px solid #fff
}
```

It will automaticly resize your list elements according to the text length.